# Turn image link into UIImageView- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I store an image link (grabbed using JS from a `UIWebView`) in a variable. I also have an `UIImageView`. Once I have that link, I want to set that link as the `UIImageView`'s value. Does anyone know how to turn that link into an asset?

Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers, Theo

Comment: your Question is not clear can you give more brief introduction or show some code what you exactly trying to do

Comment: Download image data from that link with help of NSURL.

Comment: you can use sdwebimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the image first.

**Simple version (blocking main-thread)**

```
if let url = URL(string: "") {
    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        coverImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } catch {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

**`URLSession` version (non-blocking)**

```
if let url = URL(string: "") {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: NSURLSession would be better as it will not block main thread.

Comment: You're right, just added a non blocking version. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), heres a code snippet from my project

```
 ImageView.af_setImage(
                withURL: URL(string: "your image url"),
                placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "any default placeholder"),
                filter: AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(size: ImageView.frame.size, radius: 5.0),
                imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2)
            )
```

Comment: If already using Alamofire, this is definitely the way to go! If not, I'm not sure if its worth adding such a big framework just for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm there are quite a lot of the options but based on my experience it is better to use [progressive](https://code.facebook.com/posts/857662304298232/faster-photos-in-facebook-for-ios/) JPEG, link content nice article from Facebook about benefits.

You can use [Concorde](https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde) framework to achieve this.It is quite easy to use framework.

Comment: I think thats a bit overkill, for just displaying an image?

Comment: @d4Rk Please spend some time and read about  progressive JPEG. After create demo tableview with quality images and scroll them and you will see some problems.

Comment: Ok fair enough, maybe progressive JPEGs can improve the visual performance. Maybe I didn't formulate my concern quite well. The question is just about how to resolve a link (I assume an url), fetch the image, and use it in the app (assign it to an UIImageView). There's nothing about styling it or make it look some way or another. So I think you answer is minimum one step ahead.

Comment: @d4Rk I always try to suggest approach that is a bit more than just answer to the question it is my experience. Probably you are right with own concern but it is just meter of own point of view.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without a framework? Like straight up code?